# How to "fix ENOSPC: no space left on device, write" on Mac

Tags: reactjs, web, command-line, create-react-app, inotify

I've been using create-react-app to create all my react applications. Eventually, I ran into this issue, where when I run npm start, I get this error:

```
Failed to compile

    ./src/App.js
    Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device, write
```

I've done lots of research and still can't find out how to resolve the issue. I know it has to do how many "watches" the system is set to and I've reached that limit, but I don't know how to change the limit or delete my previous watches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I bumped into the same issue today. I think you're out of space on your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered with the same problem but by running npm start command on your terminal it works.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30601578)

Answer (score 0):

Do check if you are saving your documents in iCloud and its out of storage. I faced this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove unnecessary large files from the drive or partition (e.g., C:, D:) where your project is located, and you'll be ready to proceed!